# Sort csv-data while reading, using pandas

Tags: python, sorting, csv, pandas

I have a csv-file with entries like this:

```
1,2014 1 1 0 1,5
2,2014 1 1 0 1,5
3,2014 1 1 0 1,5
4,2014 1 1 0 1,6
5,2014 1 1 0 1,6
6,2014 1 1 0 1,12
7,2014 1 1 0 1,17
8,2014 5 7 1 5,4
```

The first column is the ID, the second the arrival-date (example of last entry: may 07, 1:05 a.m.) and the last column is the duration of work (in minutes).

Actually, I read in the data using pandas and the following function:

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_data(csv_path):
    store = pd.HDFStore(data_file)
    print('Loading CSV File')
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, parse_dates=True)
    print('CSV File Loaded, Converting Dates/Times')
    df['Arrival_time'] = map(convert_time, df['Arrival_time'])
    df['Rel_time'] = (df['Arrival_time'] - REF.timestamp)/60.0
    print('Conversion Complete')
    store['orders'] = df
```

My question is: How can I sort the entries according to their duration, but considering the arrival-date? So, I'd like to sort the csv-entries according to "arrival-date + duration". How is this possible?

Thanks for any hint! Best regards, Stan.

Comment: Don't use `from_csv` it's no longer maintained, use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), you don't need to convert the time using your method just pass `parse_dates=True` to `read_csv` if the dtypes are now datetimes then you can just add them and then sort using this, you can use a timedelta to add the minutes

Comment: Ok, I agree with this : pd.read_csv(csv_path, parse_dates=True)
But I didn't get it how I can just add the datetimes :S

Comment: You should be able to do something like `df['Arrival_date'] = df['Arrival_time'] + df['Duration'].apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(minutes=x)`

Answer (score 0):

OK, the following shows you can convert the date times and then shows how to add the minutes:

```
In [79]:

df['Arrival_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Arrival_Date'], format='%Y %m %d %H %M')
df
Out[79]:
   ID        Arrival_Date  Duration
0   1 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5
1   2 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5
2   3 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5
3   4 2014-01-01 00:01:00         6
4   5 2014-01-01 00:01:00         6
5   6 2014-01-01 00:01:00        12
6   7 2014-01-01 00:01:00        17
7   8 2014-05-07 01:05:00         4

In [80]:

import datetime as dt
df['Arrival_and_Duration'] = df['Arrival_Date'] + df['Duration'].apply(lambda x: dt.timedelta(minutes=int(x)))
df
Out[80]:
   ID        Arrival_Date  Duration Arrival_and_Duration
0   1 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5  2014-01-01 00:06:00
1   2 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5  2014-01-01 00:06:00
2   3 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5  2014-01-01 00:06:00
3   4 2014-01-01 00:01:00         6  2014-01-01 00:07:00
4   5 2014-01-01 00:01:00         6  2014-01-01 00:07:00
5   6 2014-01-01 00:01:00        12  2014-01-01 00:13:00
6   7 2014-01-01 00:01:00        17  2014-01-01 00:18:00
7   8 2014-05-07 01:05:00         4  2014-05-07 01:09:00

In [81]:

df.sort(columns=['Arrival_and_Duration'])
Out[81]:
   ID        Arrival_Date  Duration Arrival_and_Duration
0   1 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5  2014-01-01 00:06:00
1   2 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5  2014-01-01 00:06:00
2   3 2014-01-01 00:01:00         5  2014-01-01 00:06:00
3   4 2014-01-01 00:01:00         6  2014-01-01 00:07:00
4   5 2014-01-01 00:01:00         6  2014-01-01 00:07:00
5   6 2014-01-01 00:01:00        12  2014-01-01 00:13:00
6   7 2014-01-01 00:01:00        17  2014-01-01 00:18:00
7   8 2014-05-07 01:05:00         4  2014-05-07 01:09:00
```